# changing on click to web page

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I really confusing about Typescript. Now I wanna make event on click button to change google website.
But if push the button, console display is displayed error message below.
[error message on console]
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/content.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

[image: button image]

My development environment is Nuxt.js using vue.js, vuetify.js and Typescript.
I'm beginner engineer and i joined the IT company a few months ago.
But my new project is based on Nuxt.js and Typescript.
Please advice me about my code below.

```
<template>
    <v-card>
        <v-text-filed><v-btn @click="onClickButton">google</v-btn></v-text-filed>
    </v-card>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import {Component,Vue} from'nuxt-property-decorator'
import axios from 'axios'

@Component
export default class typeI scriptLesson extends Vue{
    public google:any="";
    onClickButton(){
        this.google='https://google.com';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `v-text-filed` is probably a typo

Comment: Thanks for your comment! it was definitely typo. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Did that fix it?

Comment: Yeah fix it . Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v-text-filed was typo. I fix my code below. Thanks Dull Bananas!!

```
    <template>
    <v-card>
        <v-text-field><v-btn @click="onClickButton">google</v-btn></v-text-field>
    </v-card>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import {Component,Vue} from'nuxt-property-decorator'
import axios from 'axios'

@Component
export default class typeI scriptLesson extends Vue{
    public google:any="";
    onClickButton(){
        this.google='https://google.com';
    }
}
</script>
```